# VoiceOver on full-screen cells in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

I'm implementing a TableView with 3 cells and each cell fills the entire screen. Such as:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return self.view.frame.size.height
}
```

The problem is when I turn the VoiceOver on, it seems to not recognize the next element on the table and gets "stuck" on the current cell being displayed.

Is there anything I could do to induce a fluid scroll over the cells using the voice-over? I tried to find some documentation but everything I found does not talk about elements that are the same size of the screen.

Comment: Unclear what we're talking about. Only views that are on the screen can be read out by VoiceOver. So if the cell occupies the whole screen, there is no "next element on the table".

Comment: @matt Does VoiceOver read out only what's on the screen or does it browse the treeview next to the storyboard in Xcode? 

Comment: "the treeview next to the storyboard"????

Comment: @matt: indeed, in the Xcode interface builder. I thought that each accessible element in this tree was taken into account and thus read out by VoiceOver. That's not the case? 

Answer (score 0):

> You can add your table in accessibilityElements.This will solve your problem.

```
self.accessibilityElements = [tableView]
```